# Check for SQLITE DB presence

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi i'm working on one app that saves datas from nfc tag.I've created the sqlite db in a java class. I know i have to check, at the start of the application, the presence of the db but i don't know where write the code to do so.

Comment: That depends on your app, most likely on your first activity's `onCreate` method.

Answer (score -3):

I think its all depend on your app. You are check in your onCreate() method

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.